# How to exclude resources from springSessionRepositoryFilter?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, redis

We are trying to convert a legacy project to a more modern one. It was a servlet based application with jsp's, and we are moving towards Spring. We serve jsp-s, and they include many static resources.
We are using Redis as session store, and it's mapped like a filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

...

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = SpringSessionConfig.MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS)
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:redis.properties")
public class SpringSessionConfig { ... }
```

Static resources are spread in many different directories, and the problem is that, this filter runs for each and every resource, which is totally understandable.

**Is there a smart way to exclude resources from this url pattern? Or some configuration for this RepositoryFilter?**

The only solution I came up with, is to do a big refactor, and make proper namespaces for static resources, but right now, that's too much effort.

I also added resource handlers to Spring configuration, but it's ignored here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can extend the `springSessionRepositoryFilter` to implement your own filter, and then do the exclude resources in your `doFilterInternal` method, and config a `springSessionRepositoryFilter` bean manual instead of `EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation, then config the filter bean name to your web.xml.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out too. Right now I'm trying to something similar with FilterChainProxy. found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/278

Comment: yes, you can also do that, put the filter in filter chain. and then use the spring security request match